# Links In HTML For Different File Is Not Linking

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have different pages for my website and I have put those HTML files in a folder `X` and inside there are index.html, main.html, etc and there are more different pages for different articles. Now that I have separated those articles in different folders `A`, `B`, `C` for easy access inside folder `X` but now my index.html, main.html etc files are not linking to the article pages. And not even article files are linking to each other.

Look at image for a better understanding of my problem.

```
        <a class="active" href="Index.html" target="_blank">Home</a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">Anime Stuff</a>
        <a href="Youtube.html" target="_blank">YouTube</a>
        <a href="Contact Me.html" target="_blank">Know Me</a>
```

[image: Look At The Image To Understand More Clearly About My Problem!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So ***IF 'X' is your main folder*** any files in that folder will be accessed like this

```
<a href="./index.html">Index</a>
<a href="./contact.html">Contact</a>
<a href="./MainContent.html">Main Content</a>
```

For **A, B, and C** which are your sub-folders **inside X**, files can be accessed like this

For Folder A:  `<a href="./A/index.html">Index</a>`

For Folder B:  `<a href="./B/index.html">Index</a>`

For Folder C:  `<a href="./C/index.html">Index</a>`

Comment: Still, It Is Showing File Was Not Found. When Clicking On The Link. What Should I Do Now?

Answer (score 0):

Linking to Relative Page

Example:

project-folder/ 
|—— about.html
|—— contact.html
|—— index.html

```html
<a href="./contact.html">Contact</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to link between these pages is to use URLs relative to your document root. See [Absolute vs relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls) for more information, but starting each URL with `/` (making your URLs relative to the document root) will help a lot.

Example: let's treat your `Project Money` directory as your document root, and let's say these are being accessed at http://local.website.com/. This means to access your homepage, you just go to http://local.website.com/ or http://local.website.com/index.html and it loads your homepage. Additionally, http://local.website.com/contact.html will load your contact page, and http://local.website.com/youtube.html will be your YouTube page. Now to deal with subdirectories. http://local.website.com/A/article1.html will load the `article1.html` page within the `A` directory.

So to link to your `article1.html` page from anywhere else, use `/A/article1.html` as the `href` value, and similarly to link to your homepage from anywhere else, you can use `/index.html`. Using the URLs relative to the document root makes linking between pages a lot cleaner than relative to the *current path* (`./A/article1.html`, `./article1.html`, `article1.html`, `../index.html`, etc). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21828923/1499877 for additional examples, which also links to additional resources.

Comment: Man, I Am Still Running In The Same Problem. What Should I Do Now?

Comment: can you expand what you mean by "the same problem"? You should be able to use `href="/A/article1.html"` to link to your `article1` page _from any other page_ when you use the path relative to document root like this - compared to using `href="./A/article1.html"` on `index.html`, or `href="../A/article1.html"` on `/B/article2.html`

Comment: I Did Exactly What You Told Me, But I Don't Know For Some Reason When I Click On Link In The Page It Shows **"File Was Not Found."**

Comment: What is the URL of the page you're starting on, what is the value of the `href` attribute on the link you're clicking, and what is the URL you're ending up on?

Comment: Starting Page URL: (file:///D:/Madeline's%20Stuff/Sublime%20Text%203/Project%20Money/High%20School%20DxD/HSDxD.html), The Value Of The **Herf Attribute**: (<a href="/High School DxD/Contact Me.html" target="_blank">Know Me</a>), Where I'm Ending Up When I Click The Link: (file:///D:/Madeline's%20Stuff/Sublime%20Text%203/Project%20Money/High%20School%20DxD/Contact%20Me.html)

Comment: Where are you expecting to end up after clicking your link?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216169/discussion-between-woundedstevenjones-and-nelie).